# How do I enable a disabled textfield in a cell after typing in another one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a table view controller with three cells, each with a textfield where a user defines:
-Country
-State (disabled)
-City (disabled)

How do I enable "State" textfield after the user types in "Country"?

The main problem is that I'm using a model called "Field", which has a property called "depends", which shows the id of the other Field that must not be empty.

My custom table view cell has a property "Field".

If I use "textfieldDidBeginEditing()" I can only access the textfield inside the cell, not the "Field" property.

All my cells are created dynamically.

The project is in Objective-C.

Comment: Can you post some code? Obj-C or swift?

Comment: show your code it is easy to solve the issue brother

Comment: You require a button to send an action like "continue" with the code `yourTextField.enabled = YES`

Comment: SASmith - I'm having trouble accesing the "yourTextField" part.

Comment: Do you have a textField property in the custom UITableViewCell class? Is the textField property in the custom UITableViewCell private or public? Is the custom UITableViewCell the delegate of the textField or is the ViewController that contains the UITableView the delegate of the textField?

Comment: I have a textfield property in my custom tableviewcell class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short and simple:**

For short list like your (table view can place all cells on the screen) it's will be enough to keep references to all three fields:

```
// Your model
@interface AddressStorageModel : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* country;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* state;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* city;
@end
// Your cell
@interface FieldTableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UITextField* textField;
@end
// Your view controller implementation
@implementation ViewController
{
    __weak UITextField* _countryField;
    __weak UITextField* _stateField;
    __weak UITextField* _cityField;
    AddressStorageModel* _addressStorage;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FieldTableCell *cell = (FieldTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textField.delegate = self;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: // Country
            _countryField = cell.textField;
            break;
        case 1: // State
            _stateField = cell.textField;
            break;
        case 2: // City
            _cityField = cell.textField;
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Validate somehow and move cursor to next field:
    if (textField.text.length) {
        UITextField* nextTextField = [self p_textFieldNextTo:textField];
        [nextTextField setEnabled:YES];
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (UITextField *)p_textFieldNextTo:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _countryField)
        return _stateField;
    else if (textField == _stateField)
        return _cityField;
    return _countryField;
}

- (void)completeButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _addressStorage.country = _countryField.text;
    _addressStorage.state = _stateField.text;
    _addressStorage.city = _cityField.text;
}
```

**More complicated ... but simpler for future support**

But if you plan to increase number of fields you should implement your code in this way:

```
// Your model
@interface AddressField : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* value;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AddressField* dependency;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath* indexPath;
@end

// Your cell

@protocol FieldTableCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)fieldCellDidEndEditing:(FieldTableCell*)cell;
@end

@interface FieldTableCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (readonly, weak, nonatomic) AddressField* addressField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FieldTableCellDelegate> delegate;
- (void)configureForField:(AddressField *)field;
- (void)startEditing;
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray * _fields; // I left to your discretion how to create fields and assign dependencies
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _fields.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FieldTableCell *cell = (FieldTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;

    AddressField * field = _fields[indexPath.row];
    field.indexPath = indexPath;
    [cell configureForField:field];

    return cell;
}

- (void)fieldCellDidEndEditing:(FieldTableCell *)cell
{
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         [weakSelf.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:cell.addressField.dependency.indexPath
                                                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                                           animated:NO];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         FieldTableCell* nextCell = (FieldTableCell*)[weakSelf.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cell.addressField.dependency.indexPath];
                         [nextCell startEditing];
                     }];
}

@end

@implementation FieldTableCell
{
    UITextField* _inputField;
}

- (void)configureForField:(AddressField *)field
{
    _addressField = field;
    _inputField.text = field.value;
    _inputField.placeholder = field.title;
    // do all other configurations...
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length > 0) {
        _addressField.value = textField.text;
        [_delegate fieldCellDidEndEditing:self];
    }
}

- (void)startEditing
{
    [_inputField becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy, here are your steps

1. Set textfield.delegate to your UIViewController
2. Implement UITextFieldDelegate method `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
3. Check for text length if needed
4. Grab next cell that u would like to enable using following code:

   ```
   UITableViewCell *thisCell = [textView superCell];
   NSIndexPath *thisIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:thisCell];
   NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:thisIndexPath.row inSection:thisIndexPath.section];
   UITableViewCell *nextCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: nextIndexPath];
   ```
5. Call becomeFirstResponder for a textField inside `nextCell`

You will need to create an UIView category with following method for code above to work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)superCell {
    UIView *cell = self;
    do {
        cell = cell.superview;
    } while( ![cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] && cell != nil           );

    return (UITableViewCell *)cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using a tableview, I've edited the question to better define my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With a button:

```
-(IBAction) continueButton: (UIButton*) sender{

    //check if the state textfield is not empty in order to proceed
    if(![self.stateTextfield.text isEqualToString: @""]){
        self.cityTextfield.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Simple get around but not really clean.

**UPDATE**

1. Use a normal View Controller.
2. Drag a Container View into the View Controller to allow for the size of your tableview that captures data.
3. Delete the automatically generated View Controller and drag a Table View Controller onto the storyboard and embed it in the Container View (ctrl + drag and select the embed in option)
4. Set this table view to Static.
5. Drag a TableView (*not* TableViewController) into the the ViewController.
6. Ctrl + drag the from TableView to the View Controller icon and set datasource and delegate. This will allow for data to load into the tableview.

This should now solve any issues with loading data as the data will load into the dynamic tableview and the static tableview will be unaltered (if this is a viable option for you). This way you can connect your textfields to your view controller and access their properties.

If you need any help or this isn't a good solution let me know.

Comment: When using dynamic cells I don't know how to get access to the specific "cell.textfield" that I need to enable.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using dynamic cells for data gathering?

Comment: When you create the textFields for each cell you have an identifier for each one right? How are you disabling the textFields without it?

Comment: I'm getting the field data from a web service.

Comment: @JorgeChavez I have updated it. Is this a viable option for you?

Comment: I'm trying another thing: instead of making changes to the storyboard I'm looking for a way to get the UITableViewCell from UITextField, I'm using "textfield.superview", but I'm only getting the UITableViewCellContentView.

Am I on the right direction?

Comment: I don't believe so from my experience. TableViews are quite limited in their abilities and intentionally so. What do you mean by "get the UITableViewCell from UITextField"?

Comment: My custom UITableViewCell contains a property I need to know to decide if I can enable the UITextField. I've obtained UITableViewCellContentView, but I'm trying to get the instance of the UITableViewCell.

Comment: I see. Static table view cells would be hands down the simplest way of doing this my friend. I can't help much more than that as to my understanding and I may be wrong but Dynamic is designed to display captured and ongoing data and static is better for gathering data or displaying fixed amounts of data. There are work arounds for both but much harder with dynamic. I wish you luck but this option is always available should it be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

use textFielShouldBeginEditing method of UITextFieldDelegate

**Declaration**

**SWIFT**

```
optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

example-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       //do state button enabled task here
  }
```

Comment: When using this method I can only access the textfield, I need to access the uitableviewcell where the textfield is.

Comment: @Jorge-Chavez are you created custom xib for uitableviewcell ??

Comment: Prototype cell in storyboard, yes.

Comment: add a subclass of UITableViewCell and make it controller of your cell. Then add delegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: I'm doing this and I'm getting the textfield, I need to get the uitableviewcell that contains the textfield.

Comment: if you get textfield then find textfield `CGPoint` (x,y point) and then get tablecell by passing textfield `CGPoint` in `indexPathForRowAtPoint` which return the cell.